# New button on top corner of any Windows App C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms-interop

Somebody know how to add a button on top right corner of any windows app loaded?, and manage a controller to interacting with them.
Really what I want is a method to set the property "Always on top" of any form.
I appreciate any help to do this posible... :)
(my programing language is c#)

Comment: That will not be easy.

Comment: there will be little from C#....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do so but prepare yourself to get dirty. Really dirty.

See this CodeProject article: [Add Your Control On Top Another Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80255/Add-Your-Control-On-Top-Another-Application). Basically that guy is drawing a kind of custom control into another app's title bar.

In addition to this, [this article about global system hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H) might get handy for you as well.